# Are all compactly generated Hausdorff spaces regular?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

If X is a compactly generated Hausdorff space then I want to know if X is a regular space? 
(we can not expect X to be normal because there are examples of locally compact Hausdorff space that fails to be normal and any locally compact space is compactly generated) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.  For instance, let $X$ be a closed disk, let $D$ be its interior, and topologize $X$ as follows.  Say a subset $A\subseteq X$ is open iff $A\cap (D\cup\{x\})$ is open in $D\cup\{x\}$ with respect to the usual topology for all $x\in X\setminus D$.  This topology is finer than the usual topology on the disk, so it is Hausdorff.  It is not regular, since if $x\in X\setminus D$ then $X\setminus (D\cup \{x\})$ is closed but $x$ and $X\setminus(D\cup\{x\})$ cannot be separated with open sets.  Finally, $X$ is compactly generated, since it is the colimit of the spaces $D\cup\{x\}$ with their usual topologies, which are each compactly generated.  (In fact, $X$ is first-countable: if $\{U_n\}$ is a local base at a point $x$ in the usual topology, then $\{U_n\cap(D\cup\{x\})\}$ is a local base at $x$ in the topology of $X$.)

Comment: I am trying to read a proof from "a convenient category of topological space" by Steenrod that the evaluation map $ e:C(X,Y) \times X \rightarrow Y $ is continuous.He mentions that f: X to Y is continuous that for any neighborhood U of $f(x)$ the inverse must contain a neighborhood N of x; such that the image of the closure contains in U.Your construction seems to be correct.So there must be a different explanation I guess. Thank you, sir.

Comment: I think I know where my mistake was. Thanks once again for the construction.